# Вытащить переменную

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Как вывести массив,там где alert?

```
var ids = [];   
var prices = [];
var locations = [];
var raions = [];

$.getJSON('json_data.js', function get(data,key){

      $.each(data, function(key, data){
            ids.push(data.id);
            prices.push(data.price);
            locations.push(data.location);
            raions.push(data.raion);

      });

});

alert(ids);
```

Comment: какой именно массив?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman `ids`

Comment: Дождитесь выполнение ajax запроса.